# Display Error in template to User after Angular API Call error within service

Tags: angular

I would be very grateful for some help. I am trying to return an error msg in my template to the user when there is a no network connection for an api call which is inside a service.

A lot of help is out of date.

**My Component**

```
this.dataService.GetQuotePopCats().subscribe(
    popCats => {
      this.popCats = popCats['data'];
    }, 
    error => {
        this.ErrMsg = "A PROBLEM"      <<< I want to display this in my template
        console.log("ERROR", error);   <<< NEVER GETS HERE
    }
);
```

**In My Service...**

```
GetQuotePopCats() : Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'No-Auth':'True'})
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    return this.http.get(this.globals.API_URL + 'GetQuotePopCats/?action=GETPOPCATS', {headers: headers}).pipe(
        map((res: any) => res.json()),
        catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
            return of(result as T)
        })
    )
}
```

I have copied the above code and i am not fully understanding it to be honest.

Comment: Remove the catchError part. There you map the error into a valid response instead of throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you handle your error by `of` operator

```
  catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
            return of(result as T)
  })
```

in that case always will work

```
popCats => {
      this.popCats = popCats['data'];
    },
```

you need remove the `catchError` from your request or replace with this

```
  catchError(<T>(error: any, result?: T) => {
            return throwError(result as T)
  })
```